# jquery date picker not working MVC4

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-ui-datepicker

The following are my code files, I tried with these but never see any date picker popup. I don't know where the problem resides, the popup have to come on enrollementdate input box.

student.cs

```
namespace ContosoSite.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    [MetadataType(typeof(StudentMetadata))]
    public partial class Student
    {
        public Student()
        {
            this.Enrollments = new HashSet<Enrollment>();
        }

        public int StudentID { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "EnrollmentDate")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> EnrollmentDate { get; set; }
        public string MiddleName { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }
    }
}
```

create.cshtml

```
@model ContosoSite.Models.Student

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Student</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EnrollmentDate)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EnrollmentDate)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EnrollmentDate)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MiddleName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MiddleName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MiddleName)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

_layout.cshtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/modernizr-2.5.3.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.core.css")" 
        rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.datepicker.css")" 
        rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.theme.css")" 
        rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.ui.core.min.js")" 
        type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.ui.datepicker.min.js")" 
        type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/DatePickerReady.js")" 
        type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
    @RenderBody()
</body>
</html>
```

datepicker.js

```
$(function () {
    $(".datefield").datepicker();
});
```

date.cshtml

```
@model DateTime
Using Date Template
@Html.TextBox("", String.Format("{0:d}", Model.ToShortDateString()),
  new { @class = "datefield", type = "date"  })
```

Comment: any error on console?

Comment: Have you done any debugging? In the rendered html, does the input have the right class? Are you including datepicker.js and is the path correct? Are there any errors in your browser's console?

Comment: object has no method datepicker is seen on console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script>
      $(function () {
          $("#EnrollmentDate").datepicker();
      });
  </script>
```

it will help alot, using jquery files